# SQL: How do I ignore duplicates in a select statement while preferring one type of entry over another?

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, distinct

Each entry has an ID (random string of numbers and letters), a Name (string), and a type (string "A" or "B").

Some entries share the same ID and Name, but have different types.

I'm trying to write a select statement that ignores entries of type B when there is an entry using the same ID of type A.

As far as I understand, DISTINCT wont work as it relies on the elements matching in all columns, and can not differentiate based on a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
    with type_a as
        (select distinct id, name, type
        from table_name 
        where type = 'A'
        ),
        type_b as
        (select distinct id, name, type
        from table_name
        where type = 'B' 
        and id not in (select id from type_a)
        )
    select * from type_a
    union
    select * from type_b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where t.type = 'A'
or not exists (select 1 from tablename where id = t.id and name = t.name and type = 'A')
```

If the `name` should not be involved in the condition, then use this:

```
or not exists (select 1 from tablename where id = t.id and type = 'A')
```

Or use `RANK()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.type
from (
  select t.*
    rank() over (partition by id, name order by case when type = 'A' then 1 else 2 end) rnk 
  from tablename
) t
where t.rnk = 1
```

Or remove `name` from `partition` if it is not relevant.